# Pass object parameter to buildQuery in action.class

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I need to pass an object-id to a build query so i can list a collection of items from an admin autogenerated module.

here is the buildQuery:

```
protected function buildQuery($futbolista_id) 
{
  $q = parent::buildQuery('p');
  $q->leftJoin('p.mdTrayectoriaFutbolista a')
  $q->where('a.md_futbolista_id=?', $futbolista_id)
  $q->addOrderBy('position asc');
  return $q;
```

}

The thing is that i want to call this list form an editSuccess.php template and pass the object through an array, so the buildQuery get the parameter, like this:

```
<?php include_partial('trayectoria/list', array('futbolista_id' => $this->object)) ?>
```

FYI i need to get the football matches of a current football player and embed it to the edit form of the player, so i can add and edit them in the current football player form.

Comment: You need to alter Doctrine_Query in sf1.4 standard generated admin module list right? If its correct, you are doing it wrong and its possible youll found some bugs in your sollution. Standard sollution of this is to define config.list.table_method in generator.yml to some method of your model's Doctrine_Table class. There you can overload your Doctrine_Query.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved in the following way: I spent Variable not flash but for a session variable as follows

in action

```
$object = Table::Function ();
$this->getUser->setAttribute('object', $object);
```

in partial

```
$object = $sf_user->getAttribute('object');
$sf_user->getAttributeHolder()->remove('object');
```

I hope this idea will solve